# Windows 8 compatible camera implementation

Tags: .net, windows, winforms, winrt-component

I have an existing applicaton in winforms. It is using third party library (Touchless.Dll and WebCam.lib) to enable image capturing functionality. Now i want to make it compatible with Windows 8.1 tablets. When i tried to apply WinRT API in winform i got an error an error related manifest.

```
    Error   1   The "ResolveManifestFiles" task failed unexpectedly.
System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Deployment.ManifestUtilities.NativeMethods.GetAssemblyIdentityFromFile(String filePath, Guid& riid)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Deployment.ManifestUtilities.MetadataReader.ImportAttributes()
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Deployment.ManifestUtilities.MetadataReader.get_Attributes()
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Deployment.ManifestUtilities.MetadataReader.get_Name()
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Deployment.ManifestUtilities.AssemblyIdentity.FromManagedAssembly(String path)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResolveManifestFiles.IsFiltered(ITaskItem item)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResolveManifestFiles.GetOutputAssemblies(PublishInfo[] publishInfos, List`1& assemblyList)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResolveManifestFiles.GetOutputAssembliesAndSatellites(PublishInfo[] assemblyPublishInfos, PublishInfo[] satellitePublishInfos)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResolveManifestFiles.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__20.MoveNext() 4DCam
```

How to resolve this error. Somebody help me..

Comment: Likely your 3rd party assemblies aren't compatible with WinRT api...

Comment: Could you please suggest some WinForm libraries which are compatible with WinRT ?? I am totally new to WinForm.. i am stucked with this ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\Windows.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format." was my error when i try to build the application. The problem solved by unchecking '**Enable ClickOnce security settings**' under Security tab of project properties.

Another solution https://robindotnet.wordpress.com/category/clickonce-deployment/

Comment: Wow. I literally spent the entire afternoon yesterday trying to make this stupid thing work, and searching for solutions online. Thank you so much for this!!