# Wpf exe file crashes after deployment

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, windows-installer, setup-project

My wpf application uses Windows.winmd and System.Windows.Runtime dll, and I have been trying to deploy the application using Visual studio setup installer project.

When I tried to build the setup project it would silently fail and show this non-descriptive error:

```
ERROR: An error occurred while validating. HRESULT = '80070057
```

taking help from this link: [Could not load file or assembly Windows.winmd'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32783102/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-windows-winmd/32810288#32810288) I learned that when winmd files are referenced in a wpf application than files need to be manually added to the 'Application Folder', I did so, after manually adding the .exe file it added the dlls to the Application Folder, now I can build the setup project but it still shows these following warnings:

```
WARNING: Unable to find dependency 'WINDOWS' (Signature='(null)' Version='255.255.255.255') of assembly 'System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll'
WARNING: Unable to find dependency 'MATERIALDESIGNCOLORS' (Signature='(null)' Version='2.5.0.1205') of assembly 'MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.DLL'
WARNING: Unable to find dependency 'WINDOWS' (Signature='(null)' Version='255.255.255.255') of assembly 'Scout_Windows.exe'
```

Am I adding the files the wrong?

After installing the application from the generated setup.msi file, when I launch the .exe file, it doesn't start. The event viewer shows two errors, Application error:

```
Faulting application name: Scout_Windows.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0xaf6df283
Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x015909b0
Faulting process ID: 0x2f58
Faulting application start time: 0x01d4907c33342151
Faulting application path: D:\temp\scout\Scout_Windows.exe
Faulting module path: unknown
Report ID: d0cf8414-8f12-4166-8836-ba1ec5ca8c80
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

.Net Runtime error:

```
Application: Scout_Windows.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.NullReferenceException
  at Scout_Windows.App..ctor()
  at Scout_Windows.App.Main()
```

here is snapshot for the contents of my Application Folder in the setup project

[image]

I have spent two days on this error! any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you excluding Windows.winmd from the installers files?

Comment: I don't exactly know what that means! I am not manually adding the windows.winmd file to the 'Application Folder', even if I tried it shows parameter error.

I am only adding the .exe file from bin/Debug which automatically includes other dlls, I have updated the question to show the contents of Application Folder, Please view that once again